# Notification on Onfinish() function of a CountDownTimer class

Tags: android, notifications

I am trying to build a Count down timer app. where i need to notify user when Coundown ends to 0. i use `CountDownTimer` class to Count.

Here is what i wanted:

when the countdown hit 0 a notification will appear on status bar with notification tune with vibration(lets say 200ms) and when they press notification it goes the app page where they left last time(I dont want open any Activity). also if user still on the app and notification comes on status bar, When they press it,it goes right where they are(Dont want start any activity).

Here is what i already tried:

i tried notification on `onFinish()` function of `CountDownTimer` class. it work just fine but when user press the notification it just start new Activity instead of the current app page.

Its been 2 days i search for the solution still no working solution.
so Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check if the application is running in background or not and either push the new activity (in background scenario)  or leave it as it is (as user is already in app)

```
boolean isInBackground = true;
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo foregroundTaskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0);

String foregroundTaskPackageName = foregroundTaskInfo .topActivity.getPackageName();

PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
PackageInfo foregroundAppPackageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(foregroundTaskPackageName, 0);

String foregroundTaskAppName = foregroundAppPackageInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
if(!"Your App name".equalsIgnoreCase(foregroundTaskAppName) ){
      isInBackground=false;
}
```

App name should be the one in strings.xml

```
<string name="app_name">Your app name</string>
```

Comment: can you tell me where i need put notification code here with Intent? i am lost

Comment: As per your question you should put this logic here " and when they press notification".... For a sample of push notification which also handles notification click, check this link http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-push-notifications-using-gcm-php-mysql-realtime-chat-app-part-2/  . You should check the section where it handles user notification click